# Laravel upgrage 5.5 to 5.6 - routing error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have one problem after updating my Laravel 5.5 project to 5.6.

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::sortMiddleware() 
must be an instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection,
instance of Tightenco\Collect\Support\Collection given, 
called in ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php on line 676
```

My composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "ellipsesynergie/api-response": "^0.15.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
    "jeroen-g/laravel-packager": "^1.6",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1"
}
```

Comment: Have you installed [tightenco/collect](https://github.com/tightenco/collect) package previously and removed from coposer.json ?

Comment: No, I didn't do it

Comment: I found that the problem is only for versions of `laravel/framework 5.6.8`, `5.6.9`

Comment: @YuryT This was a known bug in Laravel, see here: https://github.com/tightenco/collect/issues/92. Try running `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan cache:clear` and see if it still happens.

Comment: Where you use `->sortMiddleware()` method?? can you show that code??